# Xcode 6 Installation got stuck

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I'm having weird issues with Xcode. I am trying to install the new Xcode 6 from the Mac App Store, but it got stuck at "4 minutes remaining".

Earlier I had Xcode6 GM which was working perfectly fine. I thought of downloading the new version from the App Store so I deleted the GM.

Did anybody else have the same issue?

Comment: I came here because I was convinced it was stuck as well.. no feedback whatsoever. but then I clicked "purchases" and saw xcode at the bottom just taking forever to download.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Forgive the cliche, but I had to "turn it off, then on again"  (reboot the MacBook) and only then could I re-click on the "Install" button, and it'd start downloading XCode, from scratch.

Previously, using the App Store "Check for unfinished downloads" just told me that I didn't have any downloads pending, yet in the App Store app, it had XCode stuck in the "Installing" state.

**Update**

It's that time again.  iOS 8.4 has been released, but you can only get XCode to connect to an iOS 8.4 device if you've upgraded to XCode 6.4... but you can only do *that* if you've upgraded OS X to the latest version.   Thanks, Apple.

And as usual, download times are appalling, even if (like me), you've waited a few weeks until after the release, to avoid the rush.

And when you finally *do* get to click on the `Update` button in App Store to update XCode, it changes to "Installing" but actually, it's busy spending the next few hours *downloading*, rather than *installing* anything.

You have to keep an eye on the download bar, just below the Launchpad icon on the taskbar, to check how far the painfully-slow download has got...

I'm really not impressed.

Comment: They say "History repeats itself" for a reason. iOS9. Xcode 7. Same story all over again. Been waiting >2 hours for the damn thing to update, no clue what's going on. Just a progress bar under Launchpad that seems to not progress.

Comment: Yup.  And what's frustrating is that, if any of your users have upgraded their iPhones to the latest iOS, Xcode *demands* you upgrade to the latest version to debug on them.  And you can only do *that* if you agree to upgrade to the latest OS X.  Yes, history repeats itself...

Answer (score 6):

I quit App Store, then searched for XCode in my Applications folder, clicked it, after a few seconds the download status vanished and I was able to click it again and open the app.

Answer (score 3):

If it's any help, I was in Software Update this morning updating to Xcode 6.2. For several minutes, the installer was also stuck at the 4 minutes remaining mark, and then started changing the time remaining (swapping between longer and shorter intervals). From what it looks like, this is a UI issue (probably not estimating all the time it takes to install all components), more than anything else...

Comment: Same issue for me with XCode 6.3.1 on Yosemite.  In fact the the "4 minutes remaining" would update every couple of minutes and revert back to 12 then update to 2 then back to 14 then down to 4 again, etc.   I just let the installer run for well over 90 minutes and it finally completed.  

Apple really needs to...
1) test the installer and fix these issues with the "time remaining" estimate.
2) warn the user that the installation may take a VERY long time
3) provide easy access to an installer log so that anyone can see that the installer is actually doing something.

Answer (score 3):

After clicking Install on Xcode in the App Store I got a busy-indicator in the App Store window for a few seconds and then nothing, it still just read "Install" after leaving it sit overnight.

However, I was able to download the latest version of Xcode as a `.dmg` file at https://developer.apple.com/downloads. The installation process was smooth from there.

Answer (score 1):

In App Store, try "Store" menu -> "Check for unfinished downloads..."

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Mine was stuck on "Paused". To fix it, I went to "Applications" (command-click the old version in dock -> gets you there faster) and moved to trash the Xcode app that was 337 kb in size. Then rebooted, went to the App Store and started the installation again. Turns out mine was "paused" on 2.27 gb (though I simply left my mac unattended, since the download was taking forever, and returned hours later).

Hope this helps someone, as I could not find an answer to this myself anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I updated to the last version of OSX, and then the update came automatically as a a result of that update.

Answer (score 0):

I have stuck many times, this saved me. Now you try your luck on this

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Apple should really consider having some more indication of install progress. Hard seeing any progress with the bar alone when installations exceed a certain amount of time. But then again I see apples security considerations indicating more detailed logging of the progress. I guess they oversee the few situations when updates are in the gigabyte range.

It may seem like a cancellation of the install , and going on for a second time, gives a faster install. But I would guess thats only because some of the install progress is cached.

My tip is; wait it out.

Comment: this is not an answer. check out the link on How to improve your answer
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253804/3664960